# Permanent lice prevention

Tags: treatment, prevention, parasites

My kids have changed school recently and they started bringing head lice home, at first we thought that was one time instance, but there are few families (including parents) that do seem to carry lice and don't treat them as they have nits clearly visible for some weeks now.

I went through two bottles of anti-lice shampoo and was wondering is there some treatment like dog collars for humans that one could simply carry with/on himself to avoid getting lice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the semi-permanent solution that I have found is to cover school uniforms with [Permethrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permethrin).

Permethrin is neurotoxin that is used to repel/kill ticks, fleas, and other insects and is used by [US and UK militaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permethrin#Military_use) in jungle warfare. It is considered not to be harmful to humans, but might irritate skin for some.

One can buy it on Amazon in [US](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00061MSS0) or [UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SAWYER-PREMIUM-CLOTHING-REPELLENT-Trigger/dp/B001ANQVYU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1465309512&sr=8-1&keywords=Permethrin), simply spray it on clothes after washing it should last for about 4-5 washes.